# Rename Account Exception from Account Manager

Tags: android, exception, accountmanager

I would like to ask about renaming account from the account manager. Is there someone who knows how  it works when something goes wrong (exceptions and etc)? There is nothing in android documentation about this. Will system restore the old account or leave it deleted from the account manager?

I read the android documentation and searching for an info in the medium.com and the stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename an account on Android (AccountManager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072754/rename-an-account-on-android-accountmanager)

Comment: It just bad naming of question title. Thanks for answer, but no. I wanna know what gonna happened when something goes wrong from renaming account.

Comment: I just tried using `AccountManager.renameAccount()`.  Looked like it would work perfectly.  It just deletes the account.  NOT acceptable!  I wish I could kick whomever wrote those docs in the shins.